# "+" before variable in node.js / nuxt

Tags: javascript, node.js, syntax, nuxt.js

Seen the following snippet on https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-transition

```
export default {
  transition (to, from) {
    if (!from) return 'slide-left'
    return +to.query.page < +from.query.page ? 'slide-right' : 'slide-left'
  }
}
```

I wonder what the `+` before the variable is?

Comment: It's a concise way of coercing something that might not be a number, to a number. So `+"22"` is the number value `22`.

Comment: So a short form of `.parseInt()`?

Comment: Well a short form of `Number(something)` — it's *like* `parseFloat(something)` except that `parseFloat()` allows non-numeric text after the number in a string, so the string `"123.45hello"` would be OK with `parseFloat()` but `NaN` with `Number()` (or the `+` operator)